# Deactivate Elementor Comment in Style in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, security, comments, elementor

how can i get rid off the Elementor comment in style in webpage?

```
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <style>/*! elementor - v3.15.0 - 20-08-2023 */
.elementor-widget-image{text-align:center}.elementor-widget-image a{display:inline-block}.elementor-widget-image a img[src$=".svg"]{width:48px}.elementor-widget-image img{vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block}</style>                                              <img width="43" height="36" src="https://exagon.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Logo_Nav-Bar.svg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-image-5904" alt="Das exagon Sechseck in Farbe als Homebutton" />                                                            </div>
                </div>
```

i've not found any hints to delete this.

Regards,
Jörg

I've searched for others questions mentions this situation

Comment: Why not use some JavaScript to remove all comments? https://codepen.io/AldoF/pen/eYbBrrL  (how to add javaScript to WordPress; https://jetpack.com/blog/how-to-add-javascript-to-wordpress )

Comment: Because it is still in the source code and only the DOM tree is manipulated. It should be a security measure, in which the version is not displayed and not to be the first target of an attack in case of possible vulnerabilities.

Comment: Maybe this post/answer helps you:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/356159 (stackoverflow for WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Elementor > settings > experiments and deactivate the inline experiment, update us when you can regarding this issue.

Comment: The inline comment is still there